# Convert %10.0g to date

Tags: stata

I have data with dates as:

```
    ID  Date1       Date2   
    1   1.929e+12   1.929e+12       
    2   1.917e+12   1.901e+12
    3   1.922e+12   .
```

Based on other dates in the dataset, they should be in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

Open to solutions within Stata or using different software.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your values are already date-times so all you need to do is assign a date format starting `%tc`. Here are examples using `display` on one of your scalar values:

```
. di %tc 1.929e+12
15feb2021 09:20:00

. di %tcCCyy-NN-dd_HH:MM:SS 1.929e+12
2021-02-15 09:20:00
```

See

```
help datetime_display_formats

help format
```

for how to select a datetime format and assign it to a variable.

For example,

```
format Date1 %tcCCyy-NN-dd_HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: I used the format code and it worked. Thank you!